# Talend open studio - how to proceed with next step

Tags: java, bigdata, talend

Hi Im new to Talend Open Studio , My question is, Im able to create a **Job and executing and getting output** . Say for an example following is my Job , Now **how can i proceed with the next step** , That is how can i get the code or convert it into jar or any kind of executable to get my job done every time.

[image]

Above is my Job , And i want to automate this that is i need to run this for every hour or on the fly basis . How can i do with the further steps .

As of now i  have created my Job how can i proceed with the next step

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The enterprise platforms of Talend come with Talend Administration Center that enables you to manage your jobs from a web interface and set up CRON jobs or other types of triggers. I'm not actually sure if this comes with the Talend Open Studio versions though.

An alternative is to export the job as a .jar/.war file and then have a scheduler or CRON job execute it every hour.

Answer (score 1):

Right click on your job and there's an option called "Export Job" or "Build Job" (depending on the version you're using). This will generate the java code, and puts it into a zip. All you need to do is edit the zip, open it, and in the subfolder there will be a .bat and .sh file, its basically starting a JavaVM with parameters set, and starts your job.

You can schedule this bat/sh in windows/linux to run every hour also if you double click on it, you can execute on the fly.